# Array of array of values in php?

Tags: php

I have an N amount of products with an n amount of properties.

How exactly could I use a for each inside a for each to get the properties of each product? Is it by storing an array in an array or something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear? N products with n properties each or having various amount of properties?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a main array containing arrays that represent products? Such as array(array("name"=>"cake", "cost"=>3.8),array("name"=>"cookie", "cost"=>1.75));

Answer (score 5):

```
$products = array(
    array('name' => 'Product 1', 'color' => 'red', 'size' => 'large'),
    array('name' => 'Product 2', 'color' => 'blue', 'size' => 'medium'),
    array('name' => 'Product 3', 'color' => 'green', 'size' => 'small')
);

foreach ($products as $product) {
  foreach ($product as $property => $value) {
    echo $property . " = " . $value . ",";
  }
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: This is what I assumed was meant also, +1

Answer (score 0):

If remember well you could also randomly access them using something like

```
echo $products['name']['size'];
```

or

```
$products['name']['size'] = 5;
```

if that's what you need;

For a shopping cart for example you could use for product - quantity

```
$products['apple']['quantity']++;
```